# Как вывести iframe из инфоблока в битрикс 1с?

Tags: битрикс

Не получается вывести свойство инфоблока. Вместо
видео выходит только текст с кодом:

```
<iframe class="cli-video-block__iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UvjPs-w13Hw?enablejsapi=1&amp;version=3&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer&amp;start=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;autoplay=0&amp;mute=0&amp;loop=0&amp;controls=1&amp;playlist=UvjPs-w13Hw" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

Мой код в шаблоне компонента:

```
<?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
      <?
      $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
      $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
      ?>
    <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active" data-element="9d7631ef-ec1b-4cb8-92c0-049c143e2042/d2f87e5a-183b-4795-bca5-716c1d36f6f4" data-design-nested="Слайды" style="width: 350px; margin-right: 30px">
      <?=($arItem['PROPERTIES']['VIDEO']["VALUE"]["TEXT"])?>
        </div>
<?endforeach?>
```

Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: Скорее всего, это html-безопасный текст. Посмотрите всю структуру $arItem['PROPERTIES']['VIDEO'], где-то должно быть "сырое" значение.